# Jquery "animate" and "opacity" with Chrome when change tab

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-animate

I use the following code to change the opacity of the *body* when you return to the browser tab after changing it.

```
var defaultTitle = document.title;

   // subscribe to visibility change events
   document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
   // fires when user switches tabs, apps, goes to homescreen, etc.
   if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    document.title = 'Hello!'
        }
   // fires when app transitions from prerender, user returns to the app / tab.
   if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
   document.title = defaultTitle;
   // Animation with jquery to change opacity of the body
   $("body").css("opacity", 0).animate({ opacity: 1}, 1000);
  }
});
```

This code works fine in *Firefox*, but with *Chrome* and *Edge* the body flashes once and then the opacity animation starts.
Any solution?

Here [Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/zupeta/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: what jQuery version do you use? What Chrome version?

Comment: Next time use jsbin to test and provide your work/code to test by other people like: https://jsbin.com/noxosaqesi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: jquery 3.3.1 and last version of chrome

Comment: Thank you, next time i'll use jsbin.